# dbm-gorm-diff throwing command not found error in grails 4?

Tags: grails, database-migration, grails-4

I am using the latest database migration plugin and following the documentation

https://grails.github.io/grails-database-migration/latest/index.html

The grails version is 4.0.10 and the db migration version is

```
implementation 'org.grails.plugins:database-migration:4.0.0'
```

Just like suggested in the getting started i have put the dependencies

https://grails.github.io/grails-database-migration/latest/index.html#gettingStarted

I have also put the liquibase dependency.

```
implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.6.2'
```

when i run dbm-gorm-diff, it says command not found as shown below.

it says

[image]

I appreciate any insights into why dbm-gorm-diff is not working on the latest db migration plugin. It works fine on grails 2 which i was using before. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your ran just `dbm-gorm-diff` and not `grails dbm-gorm-diff` or, better yet, `./grailsw dbm-gorm-diff`